# How to fix this generics example

Tags: java, generics

I have a generics problem and I created a simplified example.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    public interface Handler<T> {
        public String getType();

        public T getInitMessage();

        public void process(T message);
    }

    public static class MessageType1 {
        // Message type 1
    }

    public static class MessageType2 {
        // Message type 2
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Handler<MessageType1> messageType1Handler = new Handler<MessageType1>() {
            @Override
            public String getType() {
                return "messageType1";
            }

            @Override
            public MessageType1 getInitMessage() {
                return new MessageType1();
            }

            @Override
            public void process(MessageType1 message) {
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        };

        Handler<MessageType2> messageType2Handler = new Handler<MessageType2>() {
            @Override
            public String getType() {
                return "messageType2";
            }

            @Override
            public MessageType2 getInitMessage() {
                return new MessageType2();
            }

            @Override
            public void process(MessageType2 message) {
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        };

        Map<String, Handler<?>> handlers = new HashMap<String, Handler<?>>();
        handlers.put(messageType1Handler.getType(), messageType1Handler);
        handlers.put(messageType2Handler.getType(), messageType2Handler);

        String type = "messageType1"; // something valid

        Handler<?> handler = handlers.get(type);
        handler.process(handler.getInitMessage());
    }
}
```

It says:

The method process(capture#4-of ?) in the type Test.Handler is not applicable for the arguments (capture#5-of ?)

How should I modify my code to keep a collection of handlers and it should be able to call methods of these handlers with proper parameters?

Comment: `MessageType1` and `MessageType2` classes must be `static` for your example to compile (after your problem is solved).

Comment: Yes I noticed that after I posted, thanks, I edited the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the compiler is complaining is, that it cannot make a connection between the unknown type of message received from `getInitMessage()` and the type of messages accepted by `handler.process()`.

A way around it is to bind the two type parameters together explicitly using a static method:

```
private static <T> void process(Handler<T> handler) {
    handler.process(handler.getInitMessage());
}
```

You then call this method instead of `handler.process(handler.getInitMessage());`

---

The reason why compiler won't figure this on its own is better seen if we explicitly assign the message to a variable:

```
Handler<?> handler = handlers.get(type);
? message = handler.getInitMessage();
handler.process(message);
```

Now, `? message` is not a valid syntax, but I'd have to use `Object` since that is the most specific superclass common to `MessageType1` and `MessageType2`, and then it would simply be the issue of there not being any method `handler.process(Object)`.

Even if we consider that the compiler will know that `message` is not an `Object` but some `capture of ?`, the trouble is that it cannot treat that `capture of ?` as the same type as the `?` in `Handler<?>` - because if it did, this would compile:

```
Handler<?> handler = handlers.get(type);
? message = handler.getInitMessage();
handler = handlers.get(anotherType); // added this
handler.process(message);
```

You cannot prevent me from doing this using just the static type checks if you allow yourself to think that both the `?`s refer to the same type.

By using the static method suggested above, we bind the meaning of `?` for the duration of the static method, so that the compiler may treat it as the same type. I can enter the static method every time with a different type parameter, but it cannot change inside - compiler will ensure that inside the static method.

Comment: Thanks, this solution works. But it's a kind of hack, I think the compiler should notice that (capture#4-of ?) and (capture#5-of ?) are the same types of the same object. Isn't it a compiler deficiency?

Comment: @user1395515 - capture is done one each expression [individually](http://bayou.io/draft/Capturing_Wildcards.html#Capture_Everywhere)

Comment: @user1395515 added a (somewhat lengthy) explanation of why compiler can't consider the two captures as same type.

Answer (score 0):

One easy (and admittedly inelegant) solution would be to change the prototype of `process()`:

```
public void process(Object message);
```

Another inelegant solution, suggested by Jiri's answer (which is elegant), is to parametrize `main()` directly: `public static <T> void main(String[] args)`. You can then call `process()` almost exactly as before:

```
Handler<T> handler = (Handler<T>) handlers.get(type);
handler.process(handler.getInitMessage());
```

This solution will give you an exception because it involves a potentially unsafe cast. Since your interface is defined in such a way that the cast is always going to be safe, you can use the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") Handler<T> handler = (Handler<T>) handlers.get(type);
```

Both of these solutions are workarounds to give you options. Please use Jiri's answer.

By the way, you should also redeclare your message types as `static` to avoid compilation errors: `public static class MessageType1` and `public static class MessageType2`.

Comment: Your suggestions don't work because there is no <T> type in that class.

Comment: My code compiled and ran fine. A method can be parametrized individually, even if the class is not, as I have done with `main()`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html.